# prevent duplicated usernames with non-case-sensitive behavior in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, security, insert

In my website usernames are saved like this **robert** and funny thing is that one can registers with the name Robert (Capital R).

How would I prevent these somehow duplicated usernames?

My project is in mysql/php

```
  if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user_table WHERE username='$username'")) > 0){
    die("duplicated usernames can't be saved , this username exists.");
  }
```

Even with this code **Robert** can be registered.

Comment: This is really weird behaviour, MySQL queries are not case-sensitive.

Comment: show us your database schema, or do you want us to guess all that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert them both to the same case and then compare them.
As such:

`SELECT username FROM table WHERE LOWER(username) = LOWER('$username')`

Comment: Redundant, as default installs of mysql are case-insensitive with the `_ci` collation.

Comment: What if you execute the query in PHPMyadmin?

Answer (score 3):

You should add a UNIQUE index on the username column.

Also, you may find  some useful info here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+case+sensitive

Comment: Thats a poor answer. Yes it would stop the creation of the user but there should be a check before an insert is attempted

Comment: I'm guessing he has that part covered, the problem here lies on the DB side, not on his PHP code. You should read about collations and case sensitivity in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've sanitized the user input for the username to prevent SQL injections, after that, use PHP to LC your usernames before checking for duplicates or inserting the name in the database:

```
$username = strtolower($username);
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user_table WHERE username='$username'")) > 0){
    die("duplicated usernames can't be saved , this username exists.");
  }
```

Comment: You are still not matching the case of the data in the table to the case of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

php has very important function but people ignore it in start `strtolower` , use it at the time of

registering and query hence

```
  $username = strtolower($username);
```

you will never face such problem again .